# Using the header function in PHP to reload a page through AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have built a register form page. It allows you to register an account and stores it in the database.

Originally, it posted back any errors to the same page (was called index.php)

However, before leaping into the registration page I wanted to present the user with an "I already have an account" button and "make new account" button. This is because the site is for children and I didn't want to have loads of text on the same page.

So if you go here you'll see there are two options. These load in the relevant form via AJAX into the div login-register-wrapper. Click one and it loads register-form.php and the other is login-form.php (currently not working)

http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/index.php

The issue I have is that when validating, it posts back to `index.php`

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

So if you don't put in a username, instead of posting the error out it takes you back to the first page...

How can I make this work with AJAX so that it posts it out on my register-form.php file?

Here is the full register page code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'functions.php';

    if(isset($_POST['sign-up'])){

        // username
        if (isset($_POST['username'])){
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'] = $username;

            if(strlen($username) > 3){
                    if(strlen($username) < 31){
                        if(user_exists($username) === true){
                            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'That username is already taken. Sorry, please try again with a different username.';
                        } else{
                            // passed
                            // continue
                        }
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is greater than 30 characters.';
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is less than 3 characters.';
                }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The username is not entered.';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['password'])){
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

            if(strlen($password) >= 8){
                    $password = hash_function($password);
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Your secret password is too short. You should make a password with at least 8 letters.";
                }

        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You haven't put in a password.";
        }

        // Email address
        if (!empty($_POST['email_address'])){
            $email_address = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email_address']));
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['email_address'] = $email_address;
            if(strlen($email_address) > 10){ // email address less than 10
                    if(strlen($email_address) < 161){ // if longer than 160

                        if(email_valid($email_address) == false){ // email address invalid format
                                $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address has been put in wrong. Please check and try again.";
                            }
                            else{
                                // passed min length, passed max length, passed validation
                                // Continue
                            }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = 'The email address is too long.';
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "The email address is too short. It can't be shorter than 10 letters.";
                }
        }
        else{// passed (no email input)
        }

        if (isset($_POST['tos'])){
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['tos'] = $_POST['tos'];
            if(empty($_SESSION['status']['register']['error'])){
                if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){

                    // Success!!
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['success'] = true;

                    // Sends an email

                    send_email($email_address);

                } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                    die();
                    $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "Something went wrong. We're sorry. Please try again.";
                }
            } else {}
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status']['register']['error'][] = "You have to agree to the House Rules to be able to sign up.";
        }

        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What you want to do: If an error occurs on validating your register form, you want to redirect to the register page and display the errors stored in the session var. But the index.php and your ajax calls permit the register.php from loading directly into the index.php. Is that what you're aiming for?

Comment: Yes that's it. I want to reload the register-form.php through AJAX with the errors. I also want to keep the session and the variables already input and place them back into the input (which I did have working). Basically this all worked until I introduced AJAX as now the journey is different.

Comment: Best way would probably TVK's way. Or you just check for the error sessions on your index.php and decide, whether to include the register.php or the default buttons thingy.

Answer (score 0):

Headers won't be able to redirect the main page if they result from an AJAX request. Instead, you can use the AJAX callback to interpret the page result and redirect the page accordingly. A clean way of doing this is by always returning a JSON result. This could then contain a field like `redirect` that has a value corresponding to the page the user should be redirected to.

You can turn a PHP array into a JSON result using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode). If you're using jQuery, [parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is a good function to parse the JSON code. Once you have retrieved the `redirect` value, you can use `location.window = redirectUrl;` to redirect the user.